# Perform a double sort on in Grid.MVC

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, gridview-sorting, grid.mvc

So I have one grid where I display 5 columns. Out of 5, two columns are Date and Time.

User want to do a multiple sort on a grid. Initial sort is by Date when i map the data. So when the page loads it will display the initial data with order by Date. Now when i sort it by Time(HH:MM am/pm) ,grid is now sorted by time which is good but i want a way to keep the initial sort(which is by date) and do secondary sort by Time. Is is possible to do implement this functionality?

Comment: Can you combine date and time into one column?  If so, the column would naturally be sorted by date then time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add columns you can define this ability.

```
Columns.Add(x=>x.Date).Sortable(true).ThenSortBy(x=>x.Time);
```